# Proper way to populate cache from Cassandra

Tags: performance, caching, memory, cassandra

I want to have a memory cache layer in my application. To populate cache with items, I have to get data from a large Cassandra table. Select all is not recommended, because without using partition keys, it's a slow read operation. Prior to that I can "predict" partition keys using other Cassandra table that I'll have to read all again, but relatively it's a smaller volume table. After reading data from user table and creating a list of potential partition keys (userX, userY) that may or may not be present in initial table. With that list try and populate cache by executing select queries with each potential key. That also doesn't sound like a really good idea.

So the question is? How to properly populate cache layer with data from Cassandra DB?

Answer (score 2):

The second option is preferred for warming up or pre-loading your cache.

Single-partition asynchronous queries from multiple client/app instances is much better than doing a full table scan. Asynchronous queries from lots of clients distributes the load efficiently to all nodes in the cluster which is why they perform better.

It should be said that if you've got your data model right and you've sized your cluster correctly, you can achieve single-digit millisecond latencies. I work with a lot of large organisations who have a 95% SLA for 6-8ms reads. Cheers!